# log4j Rolling file appender - multi-threading issues?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Are there any known bugs with the Log4J  rolling file appender. I have been using log4j happily for a number of years but was not aware of this. A colleague of mine is suggesting that there are known issues ( and i found one a Bugzilla entry on this) where under heavy load,the rolling file appender (we use the time-based one) might not perform correctly when the rollover occurs @ midnight.

Bugzilla entry - https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44932

Appreciate inputs and pointers on how others overcome this.

Thanks,
Manglu

Answer (score 3):

I have not encountered this issue myself, and from the bug report, I would suspect that it is very uncommon.  Th Log4j RollingFileAppender has always worked in a predictable and reliable fashion for the apps I have developed and maintained.

This particular bug, If I understand correctly, would only happen if there are multiple instances of Log4j, like if you had multiple instances of the same app running simultaneously, writing to the same log file. Then, when it is rollover time, one instance cannot get a lock on the file in order to delete it and archive its contents, resulting in the loss of the data that was to be archived.

I cannot speak to any of the other known bugs your colleague mentioned unless you would like to cite them specifically.  In general, I believe Log4j is reliable for production apps.

Comment: Hi Konstantin,

That has been my observation too. I have safely used log4j for a number of years. I will investigate and report back. 

Thanks,
Manglu

Answer (score 1):

@kg, this happens to me too. This exact situation. 2 instances of the same program.
I updated it to the newer rolling.RollingFileAppender instead of using DailyFileRoller( whatever it was called ).

I run two instances simultenously via crontab. The instances output as many messages as they can until 5 seconds is reached. They measure the time for 1 second by using System.currentTimeMillis, and append to a counter to estimate a 5 second timeperiod for the loop. So there's minimum overhead in this test. Each output log message contains an incrementing number, and the message contains identifiers set from commandline to be able to separate them.

From putting the log message order together, one of the processes succeeds in writing from the start to end of the sequence, the other one loses the first entries of its output (from 0 onward).

This really ought to be fixed...